# MVC 3 Razor syntax to create RadioButtons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to create two radio buttons using RAZOR in MVC3 C#.
Shown below is an example of the intended final result:

```
<input type="radio" name="set-accessibility-on" value="on">Accessibility On<br>
<input type="radio" name="set-accessibility-off" value="off">Accessibility Off
```

`set-accessibility-on` should call an `ActionResult SetAccessibilityOn()`

and

`set-accessibility-off` should call an `ActionResult SetAccessibilityOff()`

How can I do this?

Comment: you should write some javascripts. and call the related method via ajax.

Comment: why you need razor if your functionality involves more no javascript? Html inputs are enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the markup like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="set-accessibility" value="on">Accessibility On</input>
<input type="radio" name="set-accessibility" value="off">Accessibility Off</input>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=setaccessibility]').bind('change', function() 
    { 
        if(this.value == 'on')
        //call this one: SetAccessibilityOn() -- ajax
        else
        //call the other one: SetAccessibilityOff() -- ajax
    });
});
```

Comment: pal, input is a self closing tag :)